# Bootstrap 4 checkbox changes size with background-color change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I change the background of my checkbox, the size of the check icon resizes too for some reason. How can I stop that from happening?

Take a look at my code and see what I mean:

```css
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2c2b2c;
}
.custom-control-description {
  color: #2c2b2c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 2.7;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* When I remove background the icon goes back to that default size */
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
   </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
```

Comment: Seems to run fine.

Comment: Also not seeing any issues here.  Is there a specific browser you are seeing this issue in? Can you give us a little more information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the shorthand-property `background` you overwrite all the `background-*` properties, set by Bootstrap 4. I think you want to change only the `background-color` property, so you can use the following solution:

**solution using Bootstrap 4 (alpha) - original answer:**

```css
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2c2b2c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px; 
}
.custom-control-description {
  color: #2c2b2c;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* When I remove background the icon goes back to that default size */
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-indicator {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

**solution using Bootstrap 4 (stable - not alpha or beta):**

```css
.form-check .custom-control-label {
  color: #2c2b2c;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.7;
  padding-left:15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.form-check .custom-control-label::after,
.form-check .custom-control-label::before {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
.form-check .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2c2b2c;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* When I remove background the icon goes back to that default size */
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-check">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlID">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlID">Checkbox</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What is happening using the `background` shorthand property?**

By only using the `background` property you overwrite the following CSS rules:

```
background-size: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian, for that explanation! +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {background: red;}
```

Do:

```
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {background-color: red;}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2c2b2c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px; 
}
.custom-control-description {
  color: #2c2b2c;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* When I remove background the icon goes back to that default size */
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-indicator {
  background-color: red ; /* use this instead of background: red;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">Checkbox</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: use background-color:red;  instead of background: red;